# Need name of the mentioned theorem in theory of Markov Chains with its proof.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

it this true that for an irreducible and aperiodic finite-state Markov chain with stationary distribution $π,$ the mean return time to each state is finite and equal to the inverse of the stationary probability of that state, i.e., $µ_i = 1/π_i$? I'm looking for a proof. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

we know that
$$
\mu_x(y) := \sum_{n = 0}^\infty P_x(X_n = y, \tau_x > n) 
$$
defines a stationary measure, and we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_y \mu_x(y) 
&= \sum_y \sum_{n = 0}^\infty P_x(X_n = y, \tau_x > n) \\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty\sum_y P_x(X_n = y, \tau_x > n) \\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty  P_x(\tau_x > n)\\
&= E_x \tau_x,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\tau_x = \inf\{n, X_n = x\}$ is the return time.
On the other hand, $\pi(x) := \mu_x(x) / \sum_y \mu_x(y) = \mu_x(x) / E_x \tau_x$ is the unique stationary distribution, and $\mu_x(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty P_x(X_n = x, \tau_x > n) = 1$.

Comment: but I don't know its name.

Comment: thank you very much, it helps a lot